# link QInputDialog text to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I googled about 3 hours on the internet but all the examples use input dialog's text with QLineEdit. I want to link the text to a variable to use with my list.

```
def gettext(self):
      text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Text Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')

      if ok:
          else...
```

What should I do? Here is the function that I want to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QInputDialog.gettext()` returns a tuple:
first value is the text in the inputfield (`QLineEdit`), the second is bool, `True` if 'OK' is pressed else  `False`.

so you can do:

```
def getText(self):
    text = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Text Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')    
    if text[1]:
        username = text[0]
        print(username)
```

**edit 01.03.2016:**

if you want the user to select from a list of values:

```
self.selectionList = ['Jim', 'John', 'Harry', 'Charles']

def getSelection(self):
    sel = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getItem(self, 'Text Selection Dialog', 'Select your name:', self.selectionList, current=0, editable=False)
    if sel[1]:
        username = sel[0]
        print(username)
```

**second edit:**

here a working example in pyqt4:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self) 
        self.setGeometry(200,100,300,300)

        self.selectionList = ['Jim', 'John', 'Harry', 'Charles']

        self.pushbutton = QtGui.QPushButton('Input', self)
        self.pushbutton.setGeometry(50,75, 100, 25)
        self.pushbutton1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Select', self)
        self.pushbutton1.setGeometry(50,150, 100, 25)

        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.getInput)
        self.pushbutton1.clicked.connect(self.getSelection)

    def getInput(self):
        text = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Text Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')    
        if text[1]:
            username = text[0]
            print(username)

    def getSelection(self):
        sel = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(self, 'Text Selection Dialog', 'Select your name:', self.selectionList, current=0, editable=False)
        if sel[1]:
            username = sel[0]
            print(username)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I got this error: "TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QInputDialog.getText(QWidget, str, str, QLineEdit.EchoMode mode=QLineEdit.Normal, str text='', Qt.WindowFlags flags=0) -> (str, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
  QInputDialog.getText(QWidget, str, str, QLineEdit.EchoMode, str, Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.InputMethodHints) -> (str, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool' " 

I m using pyQt4 is it the problem?

Comment: i can't reproduce your error. I added a working example in pyqt4 to my answer